# Dynamic Query in JasperReport

Tags: jasper-reports

I am new to *JasperReports* and I am trying to build a "dynamic report".

In [JasperREports ultimate guide](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/JasperReports-Ultimate-Guide-3.pdf) it's said that we can pass table names and table columns names as parameters using $P!{paramName} Syntax:

```xml
<queryString>
 <![CDATA[
 SELECT * FROM $P!{MyTable} ORDER BY $P!{OrderByClause}
 ]]>
</queryString>
```

I have created different views of my table for different period aggregations.

Then I am trying to pass the view's name as a parameter so that I can choose which period to display in the report BUT with no success.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: What's happening? Are you getting an error?

Answer (score 0):

In order to help you, we must know the error you are retrieving, how do you *execute* the report (within iReport? through a Servlet? using JasperServer?) Are these parameter instanciated? you can begin by outputing the query string, or the parameters themselves in the report, to see what sentence are you using to retrieve your dataset...